# Sharepoint Organization Chart / Browser

Tags: active-directory, organization-browser, organization-profile

How can I remove from organization chart and from organization browser, employees with specified AD group or email address e.g. user@testUser.com. Right now my chart is showing everyone. As I know I can limit results by create filter in user profile service, but in this case I need to limit results only for webparts.
Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to limit the organizational chart web part itself.  It will display everyone who has a profile in the User Profile service application.  If a user doesn't have a manager or any listing them as their manager, they shouldn't show up in anyone else's organizational chart.  That's about the only thing you could do.